# Flush data written to numeric file handle?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file-io, operating-system

How can I flush the content written to a file opened as a numeric file handle?

For illustration, one can do the following in Python:

```
f = open(fn, 'w')
f.write('Something')
f.flush()
```

On the contrary, I am missing a method when doing the following:

```
import os
fd = os.open(fn)
os.pwrite(fd, buffer, offset)
# How do I flush fd here?
```

Comment: I couldn't understand isn't the second one also in python?

Comment: @Rarblack Yes, it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `os.fsync(fd)`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.fsync) for `fsync`.

Be careful if you do `fsync` on a file descriptor obtained from a python file object. In that case you need to flush the python file object first.

Comment: AFAIK, strictly speaking, `fsync` does not equal `flush`. Both are targeting different buffers / levels of buffering. The doc also states: *If you’re starting with a buffered Python file object f, **first do f.flush()**, and **then do os.fsync(f.fileno())**, to ensure that all internal buffers associated with f are written to disk.*

Comment: You're right. When using file objects, CPython uses e.g. `BufferedWriter` and its `flush` doesn't do any low-level `fsync`, all it does is a low-level `write` to the raw stream. The way I understood the question was that the OP wanted to flush the contents of the file descriptor which is exactly what `fsync` does (e.g. [POSIX fsync docs](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fdatasync.2.html) )